# Search for text in Jasonette

Tags: json, jasonette

Is there a way to search for text on a website in Jasonette if i don't have the HTML file on my computer? Maybe over view-source:[URL] directly over the website? I didn't find anything about this topic on Google. I just have a web-container yet and now i am trying to search for text from a website using an if loop.
Something like:

```
if [text] is on [website] {
  do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
{
"{{#if $jason.url.indexOf('foto') !== -1  }}": {
"type": "$util.share",
"options": {
"items": [{
"type": "image",
"url": "{{$jason.url}}"
},{
"type": "text",
"text": "herbal57online"
}]}
}
},
```

it will filter the url, if the url contain word "foto" it will run the code